# Hide or collapse branches beginning with prefix/ when using git branch -a

Tags: git, bash, colors

We have about a dozen branches in a "folder" affectionately called `zoo` (has convenience of sorting to the end and isn't an entirely inaccurate descriptor). Essentially it's work that we might return to in a few months but don't want clogging up our branch listing.

In the visual Git client Tower, there's a nifty feature whereby the branches named `zoo/branch-a` and `zoo/branch-b` are represented as collapsed under the folder `zoo`. I know that Git doesn't actually think of `branch-a` and `branch-b` as existing within a folder, but I wanted to know if there's a way to configure the command-line `git` client to behave in a similar way.

The simplest solution is to hide these branches by aliasing something like `gba` to `git branch -a | grep -v "zoo"`, but this loses the color coding of branch types (remote/local/current) that I get with `git branch -a`. Is there a way to pass through these preferences from `.gitconfig` or to preserve the color coding provided by `git branch -a` when piping the output through `grep`?

Comment: Can't answer my own question and not sure if I should vote to dlete my own post: 

... Ok, I realized there's an easy solution to my request to pass the coloring to grep.

`git branch -a --color=always | grep --color=never -v "zoo"`

Still interested to know if there's a script to fold the folders like I was talking about...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`git branch --color=always -a | grep --color=never -v "zoo"` should preserve the color coding provided by `git` when piping the output through `grep`.

Comment: lol. thx for the response. no, but the addition of --color always to git branch -a does (see above)

Comment: I saw your comment on the question *after* I posted this answer.  :-)  I'll update this answer with the `--color=always` `git` argument.